# Where are the Mac Qt5.7 pkg-config files?

Tags: qt, gstreamer, pkg-config

I'm getting this error trying to build gst-plugins-bad against Qt5.7:

```
Package Qt5Core was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Qt5Core.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

In Qt 5.5, there used to exist a `~/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/pkgconfig/Qt5Core.pc` file. However, the Qt5.7 installation I have only has a `Qt5OpenGLExtensions.pc` and `Qt5UiTools.pc` inside of `~/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/pkgconfig`. Where did all the pkg-configs go?